# Google Analytics causes app crash: TimerTask issue

Tags: android, timer, google-analytics, crash

my app uses GAN and it crashes on a tablet saying:

```
02-14 07:27:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(28155): FATAL EXCEPTION: GAThread
02-14 07:27:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(28155): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal delay to start the TimerTask: -1510939932650
02-14 07:27:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(28155):    at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:567)
02-14 07:27:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(28155):    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:459)
02-14 07:27:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(28155):    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.connectToService(GAServiceProxy.java:277)
02-14 07:27:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(28155):    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.createService(GAServiceProxy.java:163)
02-14 07:27:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(28155):    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.init(GAThread.java:95)
02-14 07:27:44.342: E/AndroidRuntime(28155):    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.run(GAThread.java:493)
```

and even

```
02-14 07:34:38.602: E/AndroidRuntime(30648): Error reporting crash
02-14 07:34:38.602: E/AndroidRuntime(30648): android.os.RemoteException: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
02-14 07:34:38.602: E/AndroidRuntime(30648):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
02-14 07:34:38.602: E/AndroidRuntime(30648):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:2867)
02-14 07:34:38.602: E/AndroidRuntime(30648):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:72)
02-14 07:34:38.602: E/AndroidRuntime(30648):    at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ExceptionReporter.uncaughtException(ExceptionReporter.java:81)
02-14 07:34:38.602: E/AndroidRuntime(30648):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
02-14 07:34:38.602: E/AndroidRuntime(30648):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

what can I do about it? I already wrapped all calls to EasyTracker into try/catch but no result. The same app doesn't crash on a smartphone. App worked fine about half of a year.
**UPDATE**
Looks like its device or its hardware related issue, it has some problem with time (System.currentTimeMillis() returns negative). omg, its time set to 02/14/1922... thats probably the reason. However its not an excuse for GAN!!!

Comment: There is no code available cuz its google's lib (looks like you don't know what is GAN) packed into jar-file. And I can read as well :) so I know the reason is negative time.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, to used with a lot of people not actually reading their logcat, and no I haven't used GAN. I would just debug line by line to see when the exception is raised in the tablet version.

Comment: It does not point to my src and crash happens in 1-2 sec right after my app starts. It looks like its done via timer or handler.postDelayed

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was an incorrect time has been set in device. "Get network time" was checked in device settings. However its not an excuse for GAN - why should such things like incorrect system time crash applications?